# Refreshing page after function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, reload

Im using php + Jquery.
I want to reload my page at the end of "myFunction".
This is what i have currently:

```
<script>
function myFuntion(){
var x = prompt("Enter Value", "0"); //This prompts when calling myFunction()
$("#myDiv").load("config/calcX.php"); //This loads"config/calcX.php" in a Div;
location.reload(true);               //Does not reload my page...
}
</script>
```

is there something wrong with myfunction?

Comment: Do you have any JS errors during the calling function ?

Comment: Have you tried adding callback to load method?

Comment: Nope, seems like it just wont execute location.reload(true)

Comment: How shoudl I implement the callback on a refresh?

Comment: @NickProzee Like this `$("#myDiv").load("config/calcX.php", function () { location.reload(true); } );`

Comment: Too bad, no result using $("#myDiv").load("config/calcX.php", function () { location.reload(true); } );

Comment: Just out of my curiosity, if you are reloading the page immediately after loading the content of _"config/calcX.php"_, what is the use of loading it in the `div` in the first place?

Comment: @NickProzee please create [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

```
location.reload()
history.go(0)
location.href = location.href
location.href = location.pathname;
location.replace(location.pathname)
location.reload(false)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
 window.location.href = 'yourpage.com';
```